# Want to write formula in cell if x=y, otherwise blank cell, using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Let me better explain. If the value of A1 is "0" then in A2 I want the formula =vlookup(B1,C1:E3,2,0), If the value of A1 is "1", then I simply want a blank cell value for A2. I want this macro to occur upon opening the excel. I thought this would work but it is not

```
Sub test()

    Dim indicator As Value
    Dim result As String

    indicator = Range("A1").Value

    If indicator = 0 Then result = "=VLOOKUP(A3,C1:D3,2,0)"

    Range("a2").Value = result

End Sub
```

Comment: Please check out the help here to see how to ask a question. This is not a free script order service.

Comment: @teylyn the OP posted his code and we are supposed to help him with it. He's not asking for a free script.

Comment: @nicomp check the time stamps. He posted his code after my comment.

Comment: in @teylyn defense I hadn't posted the code until he made his quip.

Comment: Then I guess we should both delete our comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `ThisWorkbook` section put this in

```
Sub Workbook_open()

If Range("A1") = 0 Then
    Range("A2").Formula = "=vlookup(B1,C1:E3,2,0)"
ElseIf Range("A1") = 1 Then
    Range("A2").ClearContents
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to qualify the sheet, otherwise the last active sheet will be the target, which may not be desired.

Comment: I know, but no sheet was specified in the question so no sheet specified in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @ballsy26, that worked nicely. Just curious - what signifies that this macro occurs when the workbook is opened? Is it only the fact that it is under the "ThisWorkbook" object?

Comment: it's the `Workbook_open`. It's an event. there's a whole bunch of them, like `worksheet_change`

see [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html) for a bit more information

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code to run on a specific sheet, not the one that happened to be active when the file was last saved, then try this instead:

```
Sub Workbook_open()
Dim ws As Worksheet

' define the worksheet to be changed here:
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")

If ws.Range("A1") = 0 Then
    ws.Range("A2").Formula = "=vlookup(B1,C1:E3,2,0)"
ElseIf Range("A1") = 1 Then
    ws.Range("A2").ClearContents
Else
End If

End Sub
```